# Frequency Table with Esttab

Tags: stata

I'm interested in outputting the transpose of the tabulate command using Stata:

```
sysuse auto, clear

eststo: estpost tab foreign
esttab, cells(b)
```

Such that the output would be

```
--------------------------------------------------
                      
                  Domestic    Foreign     Total 
                        
--------------------------------------------------
Domestic               52.      22.           74
--------------------------------------------------
```

I can do something similar with the following:

```
sysuse auto, clear
est clear
tab foreign, gen(newp_`i')
eststo  : estpost tabstat newp_1 newp_2 , stat(sum ) column(variables)
drop newp* 



esttab, cells("newp_1 newp_2") ///
    compress unstack /// 
    nonumbers nodepvars noobs ///
    mtitles("Domestic" "Foreign")

...

------------------------------
            Domestic          
              newp_1    newp_2
------------------------------
sum               52        22
------------------------------
```

But I run into issues when I try to add counts of other variables (Ideally I'd like est2 to be appended vertically instead of horizontally)

```
sysuse auto, clear
est clear
tab foreign, gen(newp_`i')
eststo  : estpost tabstat newp_1 newp_2 , stat(sum ) column(variables)
drop newp* 

esttab, cells("newp_1 newp_2") ///
    compress unstack /// 
    nonumbers nodepvars noobs ///
    mtitles("Domestic" "Foreign")

g example = (mpg >=22)
tab example, gen(newp_`i')
eststo  : estpost tabstat newp_1 newp_2 , stat(sum ) column(variables)


esttab, cells("newp_1 newp_2") unstack ///
    compress  /// 
    nonumbers nodepvars noobs ///
    mtitles("Domestic" "Foreign")

...
--------------------------------------------------
            Domestic             Foreign          
              newp_1    newp_2    newp_1    newp_2
--------------------------------------------------
sum               52        22        43        31
--------------------------------------------------
```

**My desired output is:**

```
---------------------------------                                 
             newp_1    newp_2    
---------------------------------
sum (foreign)   52       22         
sum (price)     43       31
---------------------------------
```

Comment: What are the issues you run into?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The behavior of the final esttab command is as expected (horizontal concatenation of est2). The issue is that I'd prefer est 2 to be appended to the end of the table. I will edit my post to describe the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
sysuse auto, clear
est clear


rename foreign binary1

g binary2 = (mpg >=22)
unab lst : binary*

foreach i in `lst'{ 
    tab `i', gen(test_`v')
    eststo: estpost tabstat test_*,  statistics(sum) columns(statistics)
    drop test_*
}




esttab , ///
    replace cell(sum ) ///
    compress /// 
    nonumbers rename("test_1" "Yes" "test_2" "No") /// 
    mtitles("Binary1" "Binary2")

            
matrix transp = r(coefs)'               
esttab matrix(transp), compress eqlabels(,merge)
```